# white space and makefile

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++, gnu-make

Im trying to compile a project with white space into path directories.
here you have my Makefile :

```
NAME    =       ./Release/Online_pricer

SRCS    =       ./Online_pricer/main.cpp                        \
                ./Online_pricer/Currency.cpp                    \
                ./Online_pricer/Curve.cpp                       \
                ./Online_pricer/Environment.cpp                 \
                ./Online_pricer/My_convert.cpp                  \
                ./Online_pricer/My_exception.cpp                \
                ./Online_pricer/ParserTab.cpp                   \
                ./Online_pricer/Spot.cpp                        \
                ./Online_pricer/Volatility.cpp                  \
                ./Online_pricer/VolatilityCapFloor.cpp          \
                ./Online_pricer/VolatilitySwaption.cpp          \
                ../Files\\ cpp/Functions.cpp                    \
                ../Files\\ cpp/UtilitiesWeb.cpp

#####################################################                                          

OBJS                    =       $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CC                      =       g++
RM                      =       rm -f
CFLAGS                  =       -g -W -Wall -Werror
INCL                    =       ../Files\ .h/

#####################################################                                          

$(NAME) :       $(OBJS)
        @$(CC) $(OBJS) -I$(INCL) $(LIB) -o $(NAME)
        @printf "\n \033[33m[Message]\033[39m Compilation under Linux done\n"

.cpp.o  :
        @$(CC) -I$(INCL) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
        @printf " \033[34m[Compilation]\033[39m %s\n" $<

re      :       fclean all

all     :       $(NAME)

clean   :
        @$(RM) *~ $(OBJS)
        @printf " \033[31m[Delete] \033[39m%s\n" $(OBJS)

fclean  :       clean
        @$(RM) $(NAME)
        @printf "\n \033[31m[Delete] \033[39m%s\n" $(NAME)
```

When i launch "make re", i have this result :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../Files\', needed by `Release/Online_pricer'.  Stop.
```

i don't succeed to fix this problem of the directory with white space. The name of the directory is `Files cpp`.

Anyone can help me plz ?

edit : i try with one `\` and it's not working. i had this result :

```
g++: error: ../Files: No such file or directory
g++: error: cpp/Functions.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: cpp/Functions.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../Files cpp/Functions.o] Error 4
```

Comment: The problem is you have double backslashes there. Use single ones, so just ../Files\ cpp/

Comment: Try with only one backslash after Files.

Comment: it's not working with one `\\`. i joined the result to my question.

Comment: How about putting the files in double quotes? Like `"../Files cpp/Functions.cpp"`

Comment: same result as at the begining : `make: *** No rule to make target "../Files', needed by Release/Online_pricer'.  Stop.`

Comment: Couldn't you just  *not* have spaces in your paths?

Comment: yes if i have no choice. i want to be sure than there are no solutions to solved the problem. unluckily i think that i must do it :x

Comment: Try to create a link to this directory and use it in makefile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Tio Pepe suggested, you should just just create a symlink to that directory `ln -s Files\ cpp Files_cpp` (and any other file with spaces) and use `Files_cpp` in your Makefile and you **will save countless hours** of trying to figure out how `make` handles spaces.

Yes, those double backslashed are correct but later use of `$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)` and `$(OBJS)` will only screw the paths without any regards to spaces. As [this page](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/index2.php?option=com_content&id=7859) points out, you would have to decode and encode the paths - I've tried doing so in a simple example failing miserably every time, so let me tell you - you're much better off just not having to deal with spaces in paths at all. Rename the directory or use a symlink without spaces.

Comment: yeah thanks. i'm agree with you i think it's the best way. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe CMake has better handling of spaces. I'm yet to check that tool myself but it's certainly worth a try, even if only to get rid of those awful meaningful tabs in Makefiles.

Comment: Even the original author of make agreed that, in retrospect, TAB was a bad choice.  In GNU make 3.82 you can redefine the "recipe introduction character" and make it something different than TAB.  Of course this will cause your makefile to be incompatible with any other version of make, or GNU make prior to 3.82.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 8.3 file name instead
Use dir /x to see what it is

Answer (score 0):

I am super close to solving the question.   I have all my OBJFILES, SRCFILES, etc. properly formed in a fashion like this.   "/home/latency/projects/Function Pointers/depends"  ".depends"

When I go to create a build rule, is where I am running into problems.

-include $(BINPATH)/$(DEPSFILE)

```
make: *** No rule to make target `\"/home/latency/projects/Function', needed by `/home/latency/projects/Function'.  Stop.
```

I am not sure what to really do at this point.
But I am down to fixing a few build rules and I got this thing to work universally with spaces in filenames & dirs.