# Error Building Android NDK in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is my first time using `Native NDK` in `Android Studio`. 
The project I'm trying to add can be found here : https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc

I followed this guide to install `NDK` and everything related. Then I added the `jni folder` to the `app\src\main\jni` and added this line to `build.gradle`.

```
android {  
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
}
```

When I try to sync the project I get the following `error` :

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\Desktop\StarMe Git\starme_android-code\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/ThermalTake i7/Desktop/StarMe Git/starme_android-code/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\ThermalTake i7\Desktop\StarMe Git\starme_android-code\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
'C:\Users\ThermalTake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After searching for some answers I tried adding this line to the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig
            {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
                }
            }
```

And still got the same error, what am I missing? 
Is adding the `jni` folder all that I have to do?

Comment: I would like to suggest you use cmake tool chain rather than the deperecated NDK  closure

Comment: As I have understood Cmake requires the .txt file to load but this project has `Android.mk`

Comment: yes, android.mk was old way for Android native build, and now CMake is recommended for new Android native project

Comment: I provided a link to the project I'm trying to use and it has `Android.mk`, how can I convert it or what should i do with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate the build is trying to execute

```
C:\Users\ThermalTake
```

Rather than your intended file.

Typically this is due to white space being in the path. Two options are wrap the path using " characters or escape the white space (for windows try using the '^' character).

Comment: Well the path comes from `Android.mk` where is says `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` and thus it gets the white space. Can I change something there?

Comment: This was the error but I dont get the part where you say to wrap the path or escape since I am using `$(call my-dir)` as mentioned previously.

Comment: I am not the expert here but I see four options. Try wrapping like this **LOCAL_PATH:=^"$(call my-dir)^"** or  **LOCAL_PATH:=\"$(call my-dir)\"**. You may want to try with single quotes as well. Another option might be to try replacing each space character with **'^ '** or **'\ '** using the **'subst'** command: Check out this link http://blog.jgc.org/2007/06/escaping-comma-and-space-in-gnu-make.html. If you were on linux, you could prob. create a symlink to the file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514920/white-space-and-makefile/…. Last option would be to use paths with no spaces. ;)

Comment: @aGuyInLasVegas Can I use hyphen in path?